# How to get "src" attributes from a multiple nested iframe source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to fetch some image "src" from a nested iframes(s). basically an iframe inside an iframe. In my local project I somehow been able to access the iframe from my project but in my demo below there were problems in targeting the nested iframe, probably because jsbin nested my iframes in some few more iframes.

my main problem is really fetching each image "src" attributes and renaming the base url to something that I will declare later.

Goal:

1. Fetch all the image "src" from the nested iframe('box1') (source:http://jsbin.com/oqeduf)
2. Replace the base url(s) to something later.
3. Append all the image location on the body.

Problem demo can be found here: http://jsbin.com/arijuy/

Comment: Use `.find('#<id of frame>').contents()` multiple times.

Comment: I think I already did on my images_source or did i miss something. :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. I see several problems in your code: `this` is quoted, and you're selecting a `<td>` instead of `<img>`.

Comment: oops, typo error. Thanks for pointing... I tried correcting it, but it's not working yet.. http://jsbin.com/ehuqaq/

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the code is executed too quickly. When the document is ready, the iframe's contents aren't loaded yet. You have to bind `load` events listeners to each iframe inside the iframe. Then it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
jQuery("#box2").contents().find("#box1").contents().find("img").each(function() {
    // Do what you want to the image here using jQuery(this)
    jQuery("body").append(this);
});
```

Comment: jQuery("#box2").contents().find("#box1").contents().find("img").each(function() {
    // Do what you want to the image here using jQuery(this)
    jQuery(this).css('border','red solid 2px');
});

Comment: I somehow can't still target it... any idea? I just added a css property just to see if im selecting the right element.

Comment: This works fine for me... `jQuery("#box2").contents().find("#box1").contents().find("img").each(function() { jQuery(this).css("border","2px solid red"); });`